# Spring boot OpenAPI Swagger enums with empty strings generates "__EMPTY__" instead of ""

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

I am trying to generate swagger on a spring boot rest service, with the following sample schema.

```
{
"title": "HouseholdOperationsRequest",
"type":"object",
"properties": {
   "operation": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["Electrical","Plumbing","Paint","Handyman",""]
    }
 }
}
```

When testing directly (hitting the server), the validation works fine with an empty string sent in the request. However, the swagger that is generated from this represents the empty enum at the end as "__EMPTY__" and causes a validation failure for the clients sending the request with the operation value as "".

Is there a setting with swagger that can help get around this problem?

Edit: --removing Is it a bad practice using empty string in the enum.--

My requirement is a bit unusual since the downstreams treat nulls differently than empty strings. The field itself is not required and is nullable.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's not good to have Empty Strings in `Enum`, rather you should keep this field as Optional in Swagger (if not already), so user can send Null value in that case.

`Enum` are generally a Group Of Constants and Empty String is not a constant. Rather it should be replaced with Null value in general.